# Dynamic unicode message content

Tags: unicode, clickatell

My message body is dynamic and sometimes it contain apostrophe (`). For eg: Swifty’s Car

Message is not displaying correctly on the receipent phone "Swiftya€?s Car"

How can I fix this? I can not use the "Unicode Converter" tool since my message body is dynamic.

[https://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=XXX&password=XXX&api_id=XXX&to=XXX&text=Swifty’s](https://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=XXX&password=XXX&api_id=XXX&to=XXX&text=Swifty%E2%80%99s) Car

Ouput: Swiftya€?s Car

Then I converted the apostrophe to unicode using "Unicode Converter" tool

https://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=XXX&password=XXX&api_id=XXX&to=XXX&text=Swifty2019s Car&unicode=1

Ouput: ERR: 116, Invalid Unicode data

Comment: Most sites have dynamic content, and they can handle UTF-8 without problems (in fact now web is UTF-8 by default), so the problem is in the implementation: we need to know what you are doing.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi SMS does not support UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by converting it to unicode using following script

```
$smsBody = mb_convert_encoding($smsBody, "UTF-16");
$smsBody = bin2hex($smsBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solution:**
In your example you could convert ’ to ' which is in the GSM character set. If you have an interface where users type text, you could limit what characters they are allowed to use.

**How to convert to Unicode:**
Since not all characters fall within GSM charset, it may be easier to just convert all the messages.

Here is an example of how to convert your message text to a unicode string using iconv:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<form method='POST' action=''>
<textarea name='data'></textarea>
<input type='submit'>

<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) {
    $data2 = iconv("UTF-8", "UCS-2BE", $_REQUEST['data']);
    $output = bin2hex($data2);
    echo $output;
}
```

Then you send your message using that string:

```
https://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=XXX&password=XXX&api_id=XXX&to=XXX&text=005400680069007300200069007300200075006E00690063006F00640065002E20AC002E005400680069007300200069007300200075006E00690063006F00640065002C002E005400680069007300200069007300200075006E00690063006F00640065002E20AC002E005400680069007300200069007300200075006E00690063006F00640065002C002E&unicode=1
```

This example works...One of the issues you may encounter is that Unicode messages cannot be as long as text messages.